# Why is /home twice as big as expected?

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

I was checking my disk usage today, and ran the following commands (using sudo so I didn't get "permission denied")

```
$ du -hs /home
26G     /home

$ ls -la /home
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root   4096 Dec 27  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root  root   4096 Oct  1 17:39 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  root   4096 Dec 27  2017 .ecryptfs
drwx------ 53 paper paper 12288 Oct  6 14:38 paper`

$ du -hs /home/*
13G    /paper
```

Why is my /home directory exactly twice the size of my user directory, which looks like the only thing in /home?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try executing `shopt dotglob` in that same shell.

Chances are that `dotglob` is off, which causes `*` expansion (globbing) to not include files and directories the names of which begin with `.` (including the special directory entries `.` and `..` which I'm fairly certain are never included in wildcard expansion; imagine the mayhem caused if `rm -rf ./*` expanded so as to include `./..`).

Thus, when you run `du -hs /home` it counts everything in that directory, but `du -hs /home/*` expands to only `du -hs /home/paper` and so only the latter directory is counted.

Since presumably `/home/.ecryptfs` contains the encrypted data, it makes sense that it would be about the same size as the decrypted data. Therefore, the files effectively get counted twice, but only when you point `du` at the parent directory.

If you `shopt -s dotglob` to turn on the dotglob setting in that shell session, then run `sudo du -hs /home/*` again, you will likely see that it shows as the same size as if you run `sudo du -hs /home`.

Another way to demonstrate this is to put `echo` at the beginning of the command. So, for example, instead of `du -hs /home/*` you could try `echo du -hs /home/*` which will show how the `*` is expanded by the shell.

---

*As an aside,* I do recommend that you not start to habitually run everything through `sudo`. Use sudo when you must, but not otherwise. There should be no need, for example, to run `ls -la /home` as the superuser; the directory `/home` is likely to be world readable.

Comment: +1 for explaining the answer! Sure enough, /home/.ecryptfs is the same size as /home/paper. I was using "sudo" in case the directories I wasn't allowed to see were what was taking up all that extra space - I rarely use it otherwise, and I'll remove it from the original question to not confuse others.